# Don't know which monitor to install, what's BL / B / HL / H?

Tags: display

I just have bought SyncMaster S24B350 samsung monitor. I need to install the driver of it but when I open the driver program it asks me which is your monitor:

- `S24B350BL`
- `S24B350B`
- `S24B350HL`
- `S24B350H`

I dont have any idea which one should I choose.

Comment: What is the actual model number printed on the sticker on the back of the monitor?

Comment: from [manual](http://www.manualowl.com/m/Samsung/S24B350HL/Manual/278103), H has HDMI connection available, B does not. The L defines the screen width (and the weight) L=23.6"(59cm), 3.7Kg(8.2lbs) no L=24"(61cm), 3.3Kg(7.3lbs), but it's far better to read the label on the back